# Android boot/radio/vendor images: What needs to be matching?

Tags: bootloader, factory-image

Today i got a replacement phone for my nexus 5x and i wanted to use a TWRP (disk image) backup from the old one. It's running now after quite a bit of experimenting to find matching images, including the problem of images which were no longer available (i.e. radio for MOB30R), vendor.img from an older ROM (MTC19C) and the choice of several factory images. The ROM in the backup is a 6.0.1 CM13 build.

First i it did not boot, then i restored the boot.img from the TWRP backup. Then everything ran smoothly, but the phone did not recognize the radio. After flashing radio and vendor.img, it did not boot again, so i tried to flash boot,vendor,radio consistent from a factory image, then it stopped booting again, until i flashed a vendor.img from an old backup and the boot.img from the recent backup and got it working.

Now my question is, what depends on each other and what is unrelated?

- ROM version
- vendor.img
- boot.img
- bootloader.img
- radio.img

I understood the files as mostly unrelated, so that the latest radio would just improve the baseband and the latest vendor.img would have better hardware drivers, and so on. But obviously they have some more complicated dependencies.